# Why do people even play CryptoKitties?

Tags: tokens, erc-20, cryptokitties, nft

I've been lately trying to understand tokens in Ethereum, which basically makes me ponder ERC20 token standard...
I still am very much confused in all of its concepts, but the main thing that I haven't been able to understand is why people would play cryptokitties... Why would I want to pay for breeding two cats and getting a nicer breed and also, buying it from others? I just can't wrap my head around that concept...
Like WHYYYYYYYYY.....!?!???

Please someone make me understand what is even going on in there to make it one of the most famous token deployed in Ethereum?

Answer (score 1):

Why people waste money on lottery tickets?

Why a person decides to climb a Mt. Everest when there is 2% chance to die?

I think those questions are out of scope of this forum, so I suggest take some courses in human psychology. However I can answer my Cryptokitties are the most popular NFT

1. It was the first NFT token, as Bitcoin was the first cryptocurrency. The first mover advantage.
2. It is cute
3. It lauched at the 2017 peak crypto hype, timing could not have been more perfect
4. A famous VC dumped tons of money on the company, making sure that Cryptokitties have near infinite marketing budget

Comment: well, that was not the answer I wanted... and all those things you've written... I kind of went over them and still this question... Trying to know the psychology of code, programs and applications is exactly why we ask questions in a widely-used forums like this... one person cannot define what the scope of a forum is unless s/he is the creator... I am a developer and I want to know what is going on... thanks anyways!

Answer (score 0):

what makes crypto kitties valuable is its rarity and difficulty to generate, just like Gold or any other valuable asset. to generate a kitty you need to spend electricity to find a hash with specific properties

Comment: thanks @Omar, i didn't know about the hash and all... is it like mining coins? I was thinking that it is just a game that can be played by anyone and that anyone can generate a kitty as we can do it in their tutorial in almost next to no time!